# ES6 - find() is returning always true when comparing to zero

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is quite stupid probably, but `find()` is returning always `true`! Any clue why?

```
var test = [0];

!test.find((id) => {
    var comparison = 0; 
    console.log(comparison === id); 
    return comparison === id
});
// true
// true

!test.find((id) => {
    var comparison = 5; 
    console.log(comparison === id); 
    return comparison === id
});
// false
// true
```

By the way, this **only** happens with `0`, comparing any other number works perfectly. I'm probably missing something obvious...

**Update:**

This logic I'm using it to filter out an array of number from another array of numbers, example:

```
private array1 = [0, 1, 2];
private array2 = [0, 1];

this.array1 = [...this.array1.filter((branch_id) => !array2.includes(branch_id))];
```

I'm using spread operator because I need to use this class member `array1` to do other stuff. This is in an Angular/TS context that I didn't want to bring into the OP.

Comment: seems like you want `some` instead of `find`

Comment: @JonasW. Indeed, that's exactly the function I should be using. Thanks. But as the topic of the question is the constant `true` output, I'm gonna upvote or accept as correct an answer for only that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any clue why?

You are `coercing` the `find`'s output value to its **boolean-opposite** by using `!`.

It evaluates to `!0` => `true`.

> By the way, this only happens with 0

`0` being a **falsey value**, is coerced to its boolean opposite `true`

If you want to *filter out an array of numbers from another array of numbers* then

```
var test = [0];
var comparison = 0; 
var hasValue = test.includes[comparison];
```

Comment: I am using this `find()` to filter out an array of numbers from another array of numbers. What do you suggest to allow this filter to properly filter all numbers, including zero?

Comment: Following the explanation, doesn't `true === 5` = `false`? So, `!0 === 5` should equal `false`, right? Here is always true

Comment: What is the output you are looking for?

Comment: Actually, like @JonasW suggested, I was looking `some()`, just need to return a boolean id the value exists in the array. But, I still don't understand fully why I was having always `true` as an output. I even tried parsing both compared values to string...

Comment: If you are looking to return true if any item in the array match a condition, then you can use `some`. But since I am unclear on what is the output you are looking for, I would wait for that clarification. My answer only explains why you are getting the value you are getting.

Comment: Indeed I was looking for a boolean as output, therefore `some()` is the way to go. But, regarding the constant `true` output, if I'm doing `!0 === 3`, is like doing `true === 3`, therefore, why the output is not `false`?

Comment: It is not the internal comparison that returns false, `find` returns the value from the array - `0`, it is the !0 that returns true.

Comment: Ok, so, when the compared number is not `0`, it goes through the comparison and returns the correct boolean. When the value is `0`, it skips the comparison altogether and just returns the *falsey* value of `0`, and because I coerced it will return always `true`... I still don't get why it doesn't go through the comparison. Sorry if I'm being annoying...

Comment: `find` doesn't return the **comparison result**, it returns the item for which `true` is being returned, in your case it returns `0`. !0 is true, while !1 or !2 will be false.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I added some context to the OP so you understand why I wanted to use this. Using `find()` was incorrect altogether, I should have used `some()` from the start. But this allowed me to understand better some behaviors, thanks!

Comment: Instead of `some` use `includes`. Something like `this.array1.filter( s => this.array2.includes(s))`

Comment: Great, used `includes()`, is simpler and avoids and extra loop. Works like a charm, I will update my OP example just for the sake of it. Thanks!